# How to use "display: block" after clicking on the submit button?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, border

I want to change the border of an `<input type="text"`(and email)`/>` and the `display:` of a label from `none` to `block`.
I think I've done everything correctly, but maybe I'm not quite getting `onfocus` fully.
Here's the code:

```js
var nameSt = false;
var emailSt = false;
var msgSt = false;

var name_form = document.forms["mailSender"]["name"].value;
var email_form = document.forms["mailSender"]["email"].value;
var msg_form = document.forms["mailSender"]["message"].value;

function namerr() {
  nameSt = true;
  if (emailSt == true && email_form == null && email_form == "") {
    document.getElementById("email_labl").style.display = "block";
  }
  if (msgSt == true && msg_form == null && msg_form == "") {
    document.getElementById("msg_labl").style.display = "block";
  }
}

function emailerr() {
  emailSt = true;
  if (nameSt == true && name_form == null && name_form == "") {
    document.getElementById("name_labl").style.display = "block";
  }
  if (msgSt == true && msg_form == null && msg_form == "") {
    document.getElementById("msg_labl").style.display = "block";
  }
}

function msgerr() {
  msgSt = true;
  if (nameSt == true && name_form == null && name_form == "") {
    document.getElementById("name_labl").style.display = "block";
  }
  if (emailSt == true && email_form == null && email_form == "") {
    document.getElementById("email_labl").style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```css
#name {
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 22px;
  font-family: TikalSansMedium;
  font-size: 12pt;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all .1s;
}
#name:focus {
  outline: none !important;
  border: 3px solid #F8CB18;
}
#number {
  width: 300px;
  height: 22px;
  font-family: TikalSansMedium;
  font-size: 12pt;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all .1s;
}
#number:focus {
  outline: none !important;
  border: 3px solid #F8CB18;
}
#email {
  width: 300px;
  height: 22px;
  font-family: TikalSansMedium;
  font-size: 12pt;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all .1s;
}
#email:focus {
  outline: none !important;
  border: 3px solid #F8CB18;
}
#message {
  resize: none;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  font-family: TikalSansMedium;
  font-size: 11pt;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 4px;
  transition: all .1s;
}
#message:focus {
  outline: none !important;
  border: 3px solid #F8CB18;
}
#name_labl,
#email_labl,
#msg_labl {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 8pt;
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 155px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
#name_labl {
  display: none;
}
#email_labl {
  display: none;
}
#msg_labl {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form id="mailSender" method="post" action="">

  <div id="nameDiv">
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Your Name" onfocus="namerr()">
    <br>
    <label id="name_labl">This field is required.</label>
  </div>

  <div id="numDiv">
    <input type="text" id="number" name="number" placeholder="Your Mobile Number(Optional)">
    <br>
  </div>

  <div id="mailDiv">
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email" onfocus="emailerr()">
    <br />
    <label id="email_labl">This field is required.</label>
  </div>

  <div id="msgDiv">
    <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Your Message" class="mCustomScrollbar" data-mcs-theme="minimal-dark" data-mcs-axis="y" onfocus="msgerr()"></textarea>
    <br>
    <label id="msg_labl">This field is required.</label>
  </div>

  <br>
  <input type="submit" id="contact_submit" name="contact_submit" value="Send Message">

</form>
```

Comment: use onblur instead of onfocus (i think).

Comment: Also add all the tests in the submit event and return false if errors

Answer (score 1):

`onfocus` will be executed once the user clicks/tabs and sets focus to the given element. What You want is change `onfocus` to `onblur` (which gets executed once the user clicks/tabs on another element and leaves the current field).

`onfocus`: The user sets focus on the given element.

`onblur`: The user "leaves" the given element.

Comment: I'll give it a try.
But as this code is right now, should it not be working?
What is preventing it from doing its job, even if it isn't the most efficient method?

Comment: when you use onfocus, and the user clicks on the input, the validation will happen and at the time, the input will be empty because the user just focused on that input. Another way would be evaluating oninput, which gets fired each time the user writes a new character in the input.